# How to detect duplicate rows in a SQL Server table?

Tags: sql-server, rdbms

What is the most efficient way to detect duplicates in a 10 column / 50K row table? I'm using MSSQL 8.0

Answer (score 62, accepted):

To show an example of what others have been describing:

```
SELECT
    Col1, -- All of the columns you want to dedupe on
    Col2, -- which is not neccesarily all of the columns
    Col3, -- in the table
    Col4,
    Col5,
    Col6,
    Col7,
    Col8,
    Col9,
    Col10
FROM
    MyTable
GROUP BY
    Col1,
    Col2,
    Col3,
    Col4,
    Col5,
    Col6,
    Col7,
    Col8,
    Col9,
    Col10
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use `group by` on all columns and then `count(*)>1`

Comment: this works well, just remember to exclude a synthetic PK if you have one

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
Select * From Table
Group By [List all fields in the Table here]
Having Count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 3):

To detect, just group by as Guge said.

```
select fieldA, fieldB, count(*) from table
group by fieldA, fieldB
having count(*) > 1
```

If you want to delete dupes... pseudo....

```
select distinct into a temp table
truncate original table
select temp table back into original table
```

With truncate you may run into problems if you have FK constraints, so be smart about dropping constraints and making sure you don't orphan records.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the suggestions provided, I would then go to the effort of preventing duplicates in the future, rather than trying to locate them later.

This is done using unique indexes on columns (or groups of columns) that are supposed to be unique.  Remember that data in the database can be modified from other locations other than through the specific app that you are working on, so it's best to define what is and isn't allowed in a table at the DB level.