# Issue regarding string comparisons and references in perl

Tags: database, perl, string, duplicates, unique

Here is where I begin. I am reading arrays from a database one at a time using a while loop. I want to pick up on elements from the database that are duplicates (on certain fields). I want to keep only the items that are unique on these fields. Then I want to print out the data I have kept in a certain way. I created the code I thought would do it, but it gives me everything including items which are duplicates on the field. I've been searching and searching and I can't figure it out, I'm thinking, as a perl noob, I am missing something simple. Code is as follows:

```
my @uniques = ();
my $output;

while (my @itemArray = $sth->fetchrow_array() ) {
    my $duplicateFlag = 0;  
    foreach (@uniques){
        if(  ($itemArray[3] eq "$_->[3]") and ($itemArray[4] eq "$_->[4]")
               and ($itemArray[5] eq "$_->[5]" ) and ($itemArray[6] eq "$_->[6]" )
               and ($itemArray[7] eq "$_->[7]" ) and ($itemArray[8] == "$_->[8]" ) ){
            $duplicateFlag = 1;
        }
    }
    if( $duplicateflag == 0){
        $refToAdd = \@itemArray;
        push(@uniques, $refToAdd);
        $output .= "$itemArray[3]" . "\t$itemArray[8]" . "\t$itemArray[5]" . "\t$itemArray[7]\n";
    }
}
print $output
```

Comment: the code looks reasonable;  can you show data that makes it misbehave?  ideally like output from `Data::Dumper::Dumper({uniques=>\@uniques,refToAdd=>$refToAdd})` from just after the $refToAdd assignment for a row that should have been treated as a duplicate but wasn't

Comment: You may wish to use this advice to do the deduplication in SQL.  It's simpler and far more efficient.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306743/how-to-detect-duplicate-rows-in-a-sql-server-table

Comment: @Schwern that looks like an excellent way to do it. I was trying to compensate for my super noobness in SQL with my noobness in perl. I might try to implement it using that SQL statment later. I literally hadn't seen a single SQL statement until 2 days ago so this is all a little new. Thanks a lot for offering up an excellent strategy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting all the duplicates because $duplicateflag is undefined at line 13. Running a syntax test on your script with `use strict; use warnings;` on produces the following warning:

```
Global symbol "$duplicateflag" requires explicit package name at t10.pl line 18.
```

And if we scrutinize your definition of "that" variable, it says:

```
my $duplicateFlag = 0;
```

Which is to say, you have a capital F, which means $duplicateflag is not the same variable as $duplicateFlag. The check `undef == 0` still produces a true value and causes a false positive.

To avoid problems like this, always run your scripts with

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that. Thanks so much! I've learned my lesson about not using strict and warning.

Answer (score 5):

One possibility: Use hashes to determine whether or not an item has been seen before. A bit simplified from your code:

```
my %dupHash;
while (my @itemArray = $sth->fetchrow_array() ) {
    my $uniqueItem = itemArray[4];
    if (not exists $dupHash{$uniqueItem}) {
        print "Item $uniqueItem\n";
        $dupHash{$uniqueItem} = \@itemArray;
    }
}
```

Okay, it's very simplified, but you get the idea. By using a hash with the values I want to verify are unique, I can avoid the double loop and the [O<sup>2</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) algorithm efficiency. (Dang! All those years in college finally paid off!).

You'll probably want to use a more complex hash key by combining all the fields you want to search for dups on. Maybe something like this:

```
 # Probably could use join to make it more efficient...
 my $uniqueKay = "$item[3]:$item[4]:$item[5]:$item[6]:$item[7]:$item[8]";
 if (not exists $dupHash{$uniqueKey}) {
```

The main thing is avoiding looping through all unique items again and again if you can store them in a hash.

Comment: My issue had to do with capitalization, so that's fixed, whew!! Anyway, after I got it working, I thought I'd try to reimplement it this way, and got it working no problem. I really like this strategy, I had seen multiple place people say use a hash for duplicates, but I didn't get how I could use it for my specific problem. I would've never thought toput the items together like this, honestly i overlooked that. Thanks a lot for pointing this out.

Comment: You should be adding [use strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [use warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) in your scripts. That'll help you catch these capitalization errors. Using hashes to track already set data is an easy and fast way to avoid duplications.

Answer (score 4):

Possibly:

```
$itemArray[8] == "$_->[8]"
```

should be:

```
$itemArray[8] eq "$_->[8]"
```

to match all the others.

Another thing that may solve your problem is removing the quote marks around "$_->[8]". Depends what your data are.

Comment: I think == or eq will work as this field happens to be numerical. I just chose == because of that.

Comment: The smart match operator can perhaps be used somehow.. with that you can do `if (@a1 ~~ @a2)`

Answer (score 1):

SQL `group by` or `select distinct` is the SQL database way of keeping rows unique.

But if you're going to do this in Perl, I agree that hashes and keys are the way to go. However, any delimiter we could suggest, might also be there in the data. That gives you the potential for an *ambiguous* match. One hash-based method is unequivocal and uses Perl's natural structures to delimit your fields.

That is why I present the following.

```
my %uniq;

while ( my @r = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
    next unless $uniq{ $r[3] }{ $r[4] }{ $r[5] }{ $r[6] }{ $r[7] }{ $r[8] }++; 
    # unique code here
    #...
}
```

That would have eliminated the temporary variable. And so eliminated the result of *misspelling* a temporary variable. However, USUW works better for these things: USUW="`use strict; use warnings;`".